# Scala Akka Actors Example compilation error

Tags: scala, akka

Tried compiling this example https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-samples/akka-sample-fsm/src/main/scala/DiningHakkersOnFsm.scala#L1, using Eclipse.

Came back with

an error on the last few lines...

namely

```
} yield system.actorOf(Props(classOf[FSMHakker], name, chopsticks(i), chopsticks((i + 1) % 5)))
```

gives  type mismatch; found : ClassFSMHakker required: () => 0

and  hakkers.foreach(_ ! Think)
gives value ! is not a member of Nothing.

Any tips to get this to compile without errors appreciated.

Comment: Worked just fine for me when I copied it into my workspace and then converted all of the UTF-8 chars (arrows) into their ascii equivalents.  I'm using Akka 2.2.0-RC1 and it compiles in eclipse just fine

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to a sample from the snapshot docs, but your error message suggests that you are using a released (older) version of Akka.